# ng-bootstrap Popover - How to add a link to a single word from a large string

Tags: javascript, angular, popover, angular-bootstrap, viewchild

I have an icon that displays an alert for each student. It contains some big string and I am required to add some links based on some variables.

Example of alert input: 'Alex was the best student in Math with 6.'.
Example of alert output: 'Alex' is clickable (but I need to use Angular Router in order to avoid reload page). 'Alex' is a variable that I get from 'item.item.alert'.
Example of an 'item.item.alert' string: 'ALEX|MATH|6' where the first element is the student name, the second element is the course and the third element is its grade. So I format this string using 'FormatAlert' function.

Summarizing, I need to make 'Alex' or whatever given student clickable. I tried to add an click event listener but I always get 'null' of 'undefined' when I printed '#coursesAlert' using @ViewChild and ngAfterViewInit().

```
...
<ng-template #courses let-item="value">
    <!-- Template of Popover --> 
    <ng-template #coursesAlert>
        <div [innerHTML]="FormatAlert(item.item.alert) | safeHtml"></div> <--- Alert output (to fix)
    </ng-template>
    <!-- Popover Configuration -->
    <div class="hidden-md-down">
        <span>{{item.item.id}}</span>
        <i *ngIf="item.item.alert" 
            class="fas fa-exclamation-circle text-danger ml-1 mr-1"
            #popoverAlert="ngbPopover"
            [ngbPopover]="coursesAlert"
            [closeDelay]="3000"
            [container]="'body'"
            triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
            placement="right">
        </i>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

I just replicate the situation here (Objective is to handle just one word on a large text):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mdqz9b-74ins9?embed=1&file=src/app/popover-tplcontent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand is that you want to make the names clickable only. I refactored your formatGrades method to return name, and content separately.

```
formatGrades: any[] = this.grades.split("|||").map(grade => {
    let name: string = grade.split("|")[0];
    let course: string = grade.split("|")[1];
    let gradeResult: string = grade.split("|")[2];
    
    var content = " got in " + course + " the grade of: " + gradeResult + '.';
    
    return {name : name, content: content};

  });

  onNameClick(e){
    console.log('onNameClick');
    console.log(e);
  }
```

now in the UI can make the name a clickable button. you can style your button using css here too.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of formatGrades">
  <i
    *ngIf="item"
    class="fas fa-exclamation-circle text-danger ml-1 mr-1"
    #popoverAlert="ngbPopover"
    [ngbPopover]="publicAlertContent"
    [closeDelay]="3000"
    [container]="'body'"
    triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
    placement="right"
  >
  </i>
  <br />
  <br />
  <ng-template #publicAlertContent>
    <div>
      <button (click)="onNameClick($event)">{{item.name}}</button>
      <span>{{item.content}}</span>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Answer_42. It throws the expected output!